# Why the argument moving when function invoke, not same with previous position

Tags: javascript, bind

```
var years = [1990, 1993, 1996, 1999, 2002];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
   var arrRes = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arrRes.push(fn(arr[i])); // <---- look
   }
   return arrRes;
}

function calculateAge(el) {
   return 2016 - el;
}

function isFullAge(limit, limit2, el) { // now, why "this" turn position on right side (20,25,this) ?, 
   return el >= limit && el <= limit2;
}


var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);
var fullJapan = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge.bind(this, 20, 25)); // "this" position on left side
console.log(ages); // result 26, 23, 20 ,17, 14
console.log(fullJapan); // true, true, true, false, false
```

have some code, when i bind function isFullAge(this, 20,25) and invoke
why "this" move on right side ?

Comment: Not `this` (the one from the `bind` call) is becoming `el`. It's the `arr[i]` that you are passing to `fn`. Instead of passing `this`, you could have passed anything else (and probably should have passed `null`), as the `isFullAge` function doesn't use its context anyway.

Comment: ok I understand a little, but can you give me a reference article to learn my problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind maybe, if you're not already familiar with MDN?

Comment: thanks sir, sorry for my bad english
otw learning on MDN

Answer (score 0):

`el !== this`. So, I believe `isFullAge.bind(this, 20, 25)` is being misunderstood.

`this` is not an argument provided to `isFullAge`. You are calling the equivalent of `isFullAge(20, 25, i)` in the `arrayCalc` function and `this` is not used inside of `isFullAge`

```js
var years = [1990, 1993, 1996, 1999, 2002];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
    var arrRes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return arrRes;
}

function calculateAge(el) {
    return 2016 - el;
}

function isFullAge(min, max, el) {
    console.log(el !== this); // Added this here to demonstrate
    return el >= min && el <= max;
}

var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);

var fullJapan = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge.bind(this, 20, 25));
// console.log(ages); // result 26, 23, 20 ,17, 14
// console.log(fullJapan); // false, true, true, false, false
```

You can read MDN's pages on [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for some more details. I've provided another short snippet of code below that may help further your learning, in a number of ways. Best of luck!

```js
const calculateAge = year => 2016 - year
const isInRange = (min, max, el) => el >= min && el <= max

const years = [1990, 1993, 1996, 1999, 2002]
const ages = years.map(calculateAge)
const agesInRange = ages.map(isInRange.bind(`this doesn't matter`, 20, 25))
console.log(ages) // 26, 23, 20, 17, 14
console.log(agesInRange) // false, true, true, false, false
```